# Whats amusingly wrong in this code?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

Sorry for such a long code but my error is pretty amusing for me. I want to create a sorted linked list on basis of roll number of many students ---

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
typedef struct stuDetails
{
    char name[15];
    int age;
    int roll;
    struct stuDetails *next;
}det;

det *head;

void sortInsert(det *q, det *p);
void printSortedStructure(head);
void insSorted(det *p);

int j = 1, i;
int main(void)
{



    head = (det *) malloc(sizeof(det));
    head ->next = NULL;

    insSorted(head);

    puts("\n\nSorted Structure - \n");

    printSortedStructure(head);


}


void insSorted(det *p)
{
    printf("Type the name of student . Type nil to end.\n");
    gets(p ->name);
    if(j > 1)
    {
        gets(p ->name);
    }
    j++;
    if(strcmp(p ->name, "nil") != 0)
    {
    printf("Type the age of student \n");
    scanf("%d", &(p ->age));
    printf("Type the roll no of student\n");
    scanf("%d", &(p ->roll));
    p ->next = NULL;
    sortInsert(head, p);
    p ->next = (det *) malloc(sizeof(det));
    insSorted(p ->next);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}

void sortInsert(det *q, det *p)
{
    if((p ->roll > q ->roll && p ->roll < q ->next ->roll) || q ->next == NULL || p ->roll == q ->roll || p ->roll == q ->next ->roll)
    {
        q ->next = p ->next;
        p ->next = q;
        return;
    }
    sortInsert(q ->next, p);
}

void printSortedStructure(det *head)
{
    while(head ->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name : ", head ->name);
        puts(head ->name);
        printf("Age :%d\n", head ->age);
        printf("Roll No :%d\n\n", head ->roll);
        printSortedStructure(head ->next);
    }

}
```

problem is that when I run the program, it takes atmost 3 nodes and then stop working.
If I type just one node and then type "nil" as next node name, it prints first  node in result and again program stops working . Whats exactly the problem?

Comment: I am using gnu gcc compiler on windows 10.

Comment: As always: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` and friends

Comment: `... q->next->roll) || q->next == NULL ...`

Comment: `sortInsert(head, p); p ->next = (det *) malloc(sizeof(det));` - Overwriting whatever `sortInsert()` put into `p->next`.

Comment: strange code, you declare something global, but you pass it as argument through function as a function argument.

Comment: Here `printf("Name : ", head ->name);` do you see what's missing ?

Comment: `gets(p ->name);` reads until `'\n'`.  `scanf("%d", &(p ->roll));` does not consume a trailing `'\n'`.  Recommend dropping both and using `fgets()` to read a line.

Comment: Yes, thats a very silly mistake - @Michi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to insert a node in a sorted linear liked list you have to search for the predecessor node and insert the new node as successor of the found prdecessor node

```
void sortInsert(det *head, det *p)
{
    // search predecessor
    det *pred = head;
    while ( pred->next != NULL && p->roll < pred->next->roll )
        pred = pred->next;

    // insert new node next to pred
    det *predNext = pred->next;
    pred->next = p; // successor of predecessor is new node
    p->next = predNext; // successor of new node ist old successor of predecessor node
}
```

Allocate new node before you read any data:

```
void insSorted(det *head)
{
    det *newNode = malloc( sizeof(det) );
    newNode->next = NULL;
    printf("Type the name of student . Type nil to end.\n");
    gets( newNode->name );
    if ( strcmp( newNode->name, "nil" ) != 0 )
    {
        printf( "Type the age of student \n" );
        scanf( "%d", &( newNode->age ) );
        printf( "Type the roll no of student\n" );
        scanf( "%d", &( newNode->roll ) );
        sortInsert( head, newNode );
    }
    else
        free( newNode );
    return;
}
```

You can print your nodes in a simple loop.

```
void printSortedStructure(det *head)
{
    det *act = head->next;
    while( act != NULL )
    {
        printf("Name : %s\n", act->name );
        printf("Age : %d\n", act ->age);
        printf("Roll No : %d\n\n", act ->roll);
        act = act->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, recursion is not required nor beneficial in this case.

Comment: I could do like this but I read this question in a book in which it was asked to solve this without using any dummy struct variable . So it gets quite tough for me...